# SQL - return unique column values based on another column

Tags: sql-server

i am new to sql to need some help with extracting the latest transaction number for a customer code  based on a value_type column

I have the following table with these values:

```
   cust_code Trans_no    trans_Type    Time_of_trans
   RTST     RTST#289        128     2017-12-13 13:23:16.000
   RTST     RTST#290        8       2017-12-13 13:18:52.000
   RTST     RTST#291        4       2017-12-13 13:12:37.000
   NBST     NBST#789        128     2017-12-13 13:12:36.000
   RTST     RTST#293        4       2017-12-12 12:27:12.000
   DIFD     DIFD#2          4       2017-12-12 12:27:12.000
   RTST     RTST#295        4       2017-12-12 12:26:15.000
   NBST     NBST#784        4       2017-12-12 12:26:15.000
   RTST     RTST#297        4       2017-12-12 11:13:29.000
```

i want run a query that will show me only the lastest trans_no for all types for all customer codes.

I would want to the output to show something like:

```
    cust_code   Trans_no    trans_Type  Time_of_trans
    RTST        RTST#289        128     2017-12-13 13:23:16.000
    RTST        RTST#290        8       2017-12-13 13:18:52.000
    RTST        RTST#291        4       2017-12-13 13:12:37.000
    NBST        NBST#789        128     2017-12-13 13:12:36.000
    NBST        NBST#784        4       2017-12-12 12:26:15.000
    DIFD        DIFD#7          4       2017-12-12 12:27:12.000
    DIFD        DIFD#5          8       2017-12-12 09:57:44.000
    DIFD        DIFD#4          128     2017-12-12 09:53:44.000
```

Having searched around I found the following query but it only returns the last transaction time for each type:

SELECT cust_code, trans_no, trans_Type, Time_of_trans from customers t1
WHERE t1.Time_of_trans =

(SELECT max(Time_of_trans) FROM Customers t2 WHERE t2.trans_type = t1.trans_type
  )

is there a query that would return what I'm after? 
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `ROW_NUMBER`:

```
SELECT cust_code, Trans_no, trans_Type, Time_of_trans
FROM
(
    SELECT cust_code, Trans_no, trans_Type, Time_of_trans,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY cust_code, trans_Type ORDER BY Time_of_trans DESC) rn
    FROM yourTable
) t
WHERE t.rn = 1;
```

The above query will assign a row number, starting with one, to each group of records having the same customer code and transaction type.  This numbering will begin with the *latest* record, as determined by the time of transaction.  Then, we subquery to retain only the first such record from each group.

Comment: Thanks, when running the query I get the following:

Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 35
Incorrect syntax near 'PARTITON'.

I am testing this on a 2014 SQL Express instance.

Comment: Typo `PARTITON` for `PARTITION`.  Fix the typo and the query should work.

Comment: Thanks! I didn't spot the Typo. this worked perfectly. thanks very much!